# PS - Check if a text file contains lines from another file and return found line

Tags: powershell

i want to check FileA.txt if it contains lines from FileB.txt and if yes it should return that line in which the line from FileB was found.

FileA contains the filenames of a directory, FileB is a .log file from a fax software.

FileA looks like this:

```
2235375.pdf
2436317.pdf
1234245.pdf
```

FileB looks like this:

```
date_time_faxnumber_status_filename.pdf
```

I tried to use `Compare-Object`

```
Get-ChildItem -Path P:\Fax -Name | Out-File -FilePath P:\Fax\Data.txt -Encoding oem -Force

Get-ChildItem P:\Fax\OUT* -Include *.log |  
        Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime | 
            Select-Object -Last 1 | 
                Copy-Item -Destination P:\Fax\Fax.txt -Force


$Content1 = Get-Content Data.txt
$Content2 = Get-Content Fax.txt
Compare-Object $Content2 $Content1 | ? {$_.Sideindicator -eq "="} | Out-File "P:\Fax\Output.txt" -Force
```

I'm stuck at the compare line from FileA to FileB and if found return that line from FileB. I would like to have some hint in which direction i have to change my code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've read your post a couple of times, and it appears you've forgotten to _ask a question_ - so please [update your post with the question you want to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70669887/edit) - and also describe what the problem with your current code is - does it throw errors? Not giving any output? Giving unexpected output? Did the computer catch fire? :) Please be mindful that only _you_ can see your screen

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. ive added my question to the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Compare-Object` requires the values from both objects to match exactly, so it won't do text comparisons like you need. The simple way is to check each line of  `FileA` for each line of `FileB` which can be done like so:

```
$Content1 = Get-Content FileA.txt
$Content2 = Get-Content FileB.txt
$result = Foreach ($filename in $Content1) {
  Write-Output $filename
  $Content2 | Where-Object {$_ -Like "*$filename"}
}

$result
```

The result should look like this, useful if you have multiple log lines per filename:

```
2235375.pdf
date_time_faxnumber_status_2235375.pdf
2436317.pdf
20220101_010000_0001_SUCCESS_2436317.pdf
1234245.pdf
20220101_020000_0002_ERROR_1234245.pdf
20220101_030000_0003_SUCCESS_1234245.pdf
```

It's not the most efficient way, but should do what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would use the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) cmdlet which is able to

- Search for multiple patterns in once
- [Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) the input (log) file contents
- Highlight the matches

```
$Pattern = Get-Content .\FileA.txt # Loads an array of strings (lines)
.\FileB.txt |Select-Object $Pattern -SimpleMatch
```

[image]

<sub>***Note***: the **highlighting** when the output is passed to a file</sub>